# ActiveRecord: Nullify foreign key after deleting a child in self-joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, self-join

I have a self-join for my model in ActiveRecord, as follows:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id"

  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

If I delete a Manager row, I expect 'manager_id' foreign key values for all employees that were under that Manager to be set to NULL. Is this something that is handles implicitly by ActiveRecord, or is it something that needs to be defined somewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to add `dependent: :nullify` to your `has_many` association.

```
class Employee…
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id",
                          dependent: :nullify
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: Hum. True. That's what OP asked.

Comment: I am not sure that is what I am looking for. I am new to Ruby, so I might be wrong.
But basically, I have an Employee model with a self-join. I want the foreign-key manager_id to be set to null for employees when the corresponding manager (also an entity of the employee table) is deleted. What you seem to be suggesting is a different Manager class itself

Comment: @NeelVasa Oops! My bad.  I missed that part.  Same idea though. Add the `dependent: :nullify` to your `has_many :subordinates` line. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you should have the trigger be set in your database and not rely on Active Record to perform updates.

---

If you are just creating the table, you can:

```
create_table :employees do |t|
  t.references :manager, foreign_key: {to_table: :employees, on_delete: :nullify}
  # ...
end
```

---

Alternatively, if the table already exists and you are just adding the reference:

```
add_reference :employees,
              :manager,
              foreign_key: {to_table: :employees, on_delete: :nullify}
```